# Механизм возврата значения из модального окна в основное

Tags: python, python-3.x

в интернете распространён следующий пример возврата значения из модального окна в основное:

```
from Tkinter import *
# класс главного окна
class main:
  def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    self.master.title('parent')
    self.master.geometry('200x150+300+225')
    self.button = Button(self.master,
                         text = 'dialog',
                         command = self.openDialog)
    self.button.pack(side = BOTTOM)
    self.text = Text(self.master,
                     background = 'white')
    self.text.pack(side = TOP,
                   fill = BOTH,
                   expand = YES)
    self.master.mainloop()
  def openDialog(self):
    self.dialog = child(self.master)
    self.sendValue = self.text.get('0.0', END)
    self.returnValue = self.dialog.go(self.sendValue)
    if self.returnValue:
      self.text.delete('0.0', END)
      self.text.insert('0.0', self.returnValue)
# класс дочернего окна
class child:
  def __init__(self, master):
    self.slave = Toplevel(master)
    self.slave.title('child')
    self.slave.geometry('200x150+500+375')
    self.button = Button(self.slave,
                         text = 'accept',
                         command = self.accept)
    self.button.pack(side = BOTTOM)
    self.text = Text(self.slave,
                     background = 'white')
    self.text.pack(side = TOP,
                   fill = BOTH,
                   expand = YES)
  def go(self, myText = ''):
    self.text.insert('0.0', myText)
    self.newValue = None
    self.slave.grab_set()
    self.slave.focus_set()
    self.slave.wait_window()
    return self.newValue
  def accept(self):
    self.newValue = self.text.get('0.0', END)
    self.slave.destroy()
# создание окна
root = Tk()
# запуск окна
main(root)
```

поясните пожалуйста на словах в каком конкретно месте происходит отправка значения из поля slave.text в поле master.text

вот моё понимание происходящего:
после клика на кнопку slave.button происходит запуск метода self.accept. далее значению self.newValue присваивается содержимое поля slave.text. и после этого(!) модальное окно закрывается self.slave.destroy() . никакой отправки не происходит. однако программа работает, мне это не понятно. поясните пожалуйста

Comment: Не совсем понятна проблема. По нажатию кнопки `accept` содержимое `self.text` присваивается полю `self.newValue`, которое и возвращается из dialog.go, ждущий (до времени) кончины диалогового окна в своей wait_window.

Comment: тогда понятно. не знал, что wait_window() как бы останавливает ход событий.
и всё таки не очень логично это всё.после self.slave.destroy() объекта уже не существует. но тем не менее несуществующий объект как-то передаёт newValue

Comment: @Sergey Kalinin 

     16.2.2 Common Widget Methods
       w.wait_window(w)
           Wait until window w is destroyed.